# Product API Error for Amazon France Items

Tags: amazon-product-api

I try to get information about items using Amazon Product API (for example http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html# ).
There is no problem for items from amazon.com(US), but for some items from amazon.fr, amazon.de API returns:

> Error! AWS.InvalidParameterValue HTTP Status 200: Success B01B8E8OP4
>   is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry
>   your request.

But https://www.amazon.fr/Ravensburger-24011-Jeu-Educatif-Colorino/dp/B01B8E8OP4/ref=lp_10946356031_1_1?s=toys&ie=UTF8&qid=1515158225&sr=1-1 is present.

I have registration as associate at amazon.fr and use appropriate associate tag.

For amazon.de:

> Error! AWS.InvalidParameterValue HTTP Status 200: Success B014FSAOYE
>   is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry
>   your request.

but https://www.amazon.de/dp/B014FSAOYE/ref=sspa_dk_detail_5?psc=1

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because different API endpoins for each location https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Locales.html

And enpoind URL for request must be:

```
https://webservices.amazon.fr/onca/xml
```